# App contains both online video and offline services. How does Apple defines it for 30% charges?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval, iosdeployment

we have an app which has both services at 30% online video and 70% offline onsite serivce for customers. As the policy defined by Apple company that any online service virtual through APP will be charged 30% of total amount.

The problem is that our app is not a full virtual services providing to customers but offline onsite services are also involved. 
What will Apple company define our app according to their policy?
What is a better way for us to avoid the 30% charge collected by Apple Company?

I will so appreciate if any replies or advice.

Comment: You can make it so that they access videos that they have purchased on your web site through your app but you cannot allow them to purchase videos in your app - something like how the Kindle store/app works.

Comment: @jianlu Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points you may like to see :

1. If you are using Consumable or non consumable inApp purchases than there will be fix 30% charges will be taken from Apple. And that will be fix in all cases of this types of inApp purchases. Developers already requested to Apple to reduce this charges to 15% but yet rates are same.
2. If you are using subscription based inApp purchases than the rates will the same 30% for the first year. After the 1 year rates will be changed to 15%. So after 1 year of subscription period you will get 85% of amount from original.

**Important Note :**

- Above facts & figures are according to the current rules & regulations stated in Apple's official Site. So there is no chances of getting anything wrong.

Hope this will help everyone.

Comment: We consider making consumers purchase on the web and only play the videos in App. Thanks for your help :)